# Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage)

Tags: sql, error-handling, bulkinsert

I am trying to use bulk insert to upload a txt file into a database I created.
Here is the script:

```
create table Producer(
    ProducerID              char(10)    not null primary key,
    Producer                        varchar(25)     not null,
    ListPrice                   int     null,
    Quantity                    int         not null
)
```

When I try to run the file, this error pops up:

> Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified as char.
> DataFileType will be assumed to be widechar because the data file has
> a Unicode signature. Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified
> as char. DataFileType will be assumed to be widechar because the data
> file has a Unicode signature. Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk
> load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the
> specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (Quantity). Msg 4864, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or
> invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 3
> (ListPrice). Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load data
> conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
> codepage) for row 3, column 4 (Quantity). Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1,
> Line 2 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid
> character for the specified codepage) for row 4, column 4 (Quantity).
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load data conversion error
> (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
> row 5, column 4 (Quantity). Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk
> load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the
> specified codepage) for row 6, column 4 (Quantity). Msg 4864, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or
> invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 7, column 4
> (Quantity). Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load data
> conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
> codepage) for row 8, column 4 (Quantity). Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1,
> Line 2 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid
> character for the specified codepage) for row 9, column 4 (Quantity).
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load data conversion error
> (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
> row 10, column 4 (Quantity). Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk
> load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the
> specified codepage) for row 11, column 4 (Quantity). Msg 4865, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 2 Cannot bulk load because the maximum number of
> errors (10) was exceeded. Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The OLE
> DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The
> provider did not give any information about the error. Msg 7330, Level
> 16, State 2, Line 2 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for
> linked server "(null)".

Originally I was using an excel file and that didn't work, so I converted it to a .txt.  That didn't work, and I am really clueless as to what to do.
[This is what the file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Cqi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding the `DATAFILETYPE = ‘widechar’` to the BULK INSERT statement

```
DATAFILETYPE = { 'char' | 'native' | 'widechar' | 'widenative' }
```

Specifies that BULK INSERT performs the import operation using the specified data-file type value.

```
Widechar = Unicode characters
```